# bindTaskEvents function isn't called 2nd time

Tags: javascript, dom

iam making a to do list app just using javascript... in which you can add tasks edit them and delete.but my edit task function is working for the list items with which are there in html document before dom manipulation but after i add new elements it doesn't work for newly appended elements

```
    //Problem: User interaction doesn't provide desired results.
//Solution: Add interactivty so the user can manage daily tasks.

var taskInput = document.getElementById('new-task'); //new-task
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]; //first button
var incompleteTasksHolder = document.getElementById('incomplete-tasks'); //incompleteTasks
var completedTasksHolder = document.getElementById('completed-tasks');  //completedTasks

//new task list item 
var createNewTaskElement = function(taskString){
    //create listItem
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');

    //input(checkbox)
    var checkBox = document.createElement('input');

    //label
    var label = document.createElement('label');

    //input(text)
    var editInput = document.createElement('input');

    //button.edit
    var editButton = document.createElement('button');

    //button.delete
    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

    //Each element needs modifying
    checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
    editInput.type = 'text';

    editButton.innerText = 'edit';
    editButton.className = 'edit';
    deleteButton.innerText = 'delete';
    deleteButton.className = 'delete';

    label.innerText = taskString;

    //Each elements needs appended
    listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
    listItem.appendChild(label);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

    return listItem; 
}

//Add a new task
var addTask = function(){
  //Create a new list item with the text from #new-task:
    var listItem = createNewTaskElement(taskInput.value);

    //append listItems to incomplete tasks holder
    incompleteTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
}

//Edit an existing task
var editTask = function(){
    console.log('the edit task function is running');
    var listItem = this.parentNode;

    var editInput = listItem.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
    var label = listItem.querySelector('label');

    var containsClass = listItem.classList.contains('editMode');
    //if the class of the parent is .editMode
    if(containsClass){
        //Switch from .editMode
        //label text become the input's value
        label.innerText = editInput.value;
    }else{
      //Switch to .editMode
      //input value becomes the label's text
        editInput.value = label.innerText;
    }
    //Toggle .editMode on the listItem
    listItem.classList.toggle('editMode');
}

//Delete an existing task
var deleteTask = function(){
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    var ul = listItem.parentNode;
    //Remove the parent list item from the ul
    ul.removeChild(listItem);
}

//Mark a task as complete
var taskCompleted = function() {
  console.log("Task complete...");
  //Append the task list item to the #completed-tasks
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  completedTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvents(listItem,taskIncomplete);
}

//Mark a task as incomplete
var taskIncomplete = function(){
    //Append the task list item to the #incomplete-tasks
    var listItem = this.parentNode;
    incompleteTasksHolder.appendChild(listItem);
    bindTaskEvents(listItem,taskCompleted);
}

//Set the click handler to the addTask function
addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);

var bindTaskEvents = function(taskListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {
  console.log("Bind list item events");
  //select taskListItem's children
  var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
  var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
  var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

  //bind editTask to edit button
  editButton.onclick = editTask;

  //bind deleteTask to delete button
  deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

  //bind checkBoxEventHandler to checkbox
  checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;


}

//cycle over incompletetaskHolder ul list items
for(var i = 0; i < incompleteTasksHolder.children.length; i++){
    //bind events to list's item children(taskCompleted)
    bindTaskEvents(incompleteTasksHolder.children[i], taskCompleted);
}

//cycle over completedTasksHolder ul list items
for(var i = 0; i < completedTasksHolder.children.length; i++){
  //bind events to list item's children (taskIncomplete)
  bindTaskEvents(completedTasksHolder.children[i], taskIncomplete);
}
```

Comment: An `event` cannot be attached to an `undefined` Element.

Comment: Please show code in use. I don't see `bindTaskEvents` being called. It would help if you would indent your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

An `event` cannot be attached to an `undefined` Element. Solution: attach events after definition.

Comment: wil you please be more specific.